# Numpy: Trying to set value on a slice of a slice of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I've been trying to perform the following:

Given an array, select a first set of indices. Then select another set of indices, and change the value of the array to some other value.

Sample code:

```
r = np.random.randn(15)
ind_a = [0, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 14]
ind_b = [0, 4, 5]
r[ind_a][ind_b] = 1
```

I want to be able to set the 0th, 4th, and 5th indices of the first set of indices to 1. So this would be the 0th, 8th, and 9th indices of the original array to 1.

But the code I'm using isn't working. Is there some other way to get this done? I've spent a few hours going through stuff on boolean masks and fancy indexing trying to circumvent the issue but cant seem to figure it out.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `r[ind_a]` is a new array with copied values.  `[ind_b]=1` is modifying that copy, not the original `r`.  You need an single index that combines the selection of both.

Comment: I assumed so, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that in this situation

Comment: Convert `ind_a` to an array and then use `r[ind_a[ind_b]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slice `ind_a` first:

```
r[np.array(ind_a)[ind_b]] = 1
print(r)
array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

Answer (score 1):

I am slightly confused by the wording of your question, but let me see if this helps.

Question: Take numbers from ind_b as indexes for ind_a. Use the selected numbers from ind_a as the indexes of r that should be set to 1.

Answer:
Use a for loop, as follows:

```
for i in ind_b:
    j = ind_a[i]
    r[j] = 1
```

This will change r as follows:

```
>>> r
[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 1, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```